# How can I use Name Tag on a touch screen device?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been trying to name a sheep jeb and all it does is hit the sheep. I'm on touch screen on my tablet and cannot find a solution. Please help. Is it even possible without a mouse/controller?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet on the mouse but I have done the nametag thing multiple times on touchpads. All you do is tap and hold it until you named the entity or face the entity until a button that says "name" appears above your hotbar. 
Just remember to not hit the entity by tapping once on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a name tag and an anvil. You use the anvil to rename the name tag. Once you’ve done that if you press and hold on the animal you want to name an icon will appear. It should say name. Click on it and then you have named the animal!